# Magento install stops creating database

Tags: windows, magento, installation

I've tried win xp and 7
Apache 2.2.19
php-5.3.6 (tried php 5.1.x)
Mysql 5.1.44

The install process runs ok until the database creation screen.
After 1 minute, the process stops at:
http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/
with a BLANK page

The database has only 199 tables (sometimes stops with less tables)

If i refresh the webpage, sometimes more tables are created, but then i get a database error.

Tried to IMPORT the database manually and start the install, but i get an error at the same step!

Also retried the install (deleting the cached data in the Magento folder).

What am i doing wrong?

thanks.

Comment: Check max_input_time and max_execution_time.It should be more than 30.

Comment: The ONLY way i could find to install Magento on Windows (xp / 7) was to install XAMPP first. Don't really understand why.

Answer (score 3):

I used to get the same behavior. Other observation is you do not get the blank screen if you are running installation wizard while magento sample data imported to the database. 
I did some googling and find the following poge which resolved my issue.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/76240/

that is modify apache httpd.conf and add following lines:

Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest trying to install via the Command Line Interface:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/command_line_installation_wizard

Comment: Any idea how can i use that command line in Windows? CMD does not accept that syntax...

Comment: This is a very good solution as it also prevents apache timeouts. Look into the /install.php file to see which parameters are available (in the link provided by this answer are not all parameters listed).

Answer (score 1):

Open the index.php file (at the root) and write the following line at the top

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
?>
```

Empty the tables in your database and try again. The white page appears because the script times out and when you refresh that same page Magento gives you an error page where it says the table already exists. The SQL script which creates the tables in the database does not check whether the table exists in the database or not.

Answer (score 0):

A blank screen in PHP is a strong sign of running out of memory. Check the memory limit according to [the requirements](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements) and then maybe add a bit more too.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name localhost file

with any www.example123.com in

c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

and add

127.0.0.1 www.example123.com

after wards follow these steps through this torrent link.

http://tinyurl.com/3r6dpop

---

After installing some images may not upload so even uploaded the books.

Answer (score 0):

I got blank screen too, and the following error:

> [09-Feb-2012 15:27:43] PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30
>   seconds exceeded in D:\creation\software
>   developer\projects\magento\document root\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php
>   on line 228

I'm pretty sure, that you have execution timeout too...

You have to setup your php.ini, and increase the max_execution_timeout, and in the iis manager you have to increase the fastcgi request and activity timeouts too.